# In Katalon Studio the recorder and playback is not supported for new Chrome version

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

Katalon Studio is not supported in the new version of chrome. I tried Katalon Recorder extension and the drag and drop file upload is not working. How can I handle it?

Comment: This is a broad question and probably needs to be directed at the makers of Katalon.

Answer (score 0):

After Chrome updated to v74, you might be getting the following error message:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73
```

Until Katalon Studio gets updated, try the following workaround from Katalon [forum](https://forum.katalon.com/t/unable-to-open-chrome-driver-browser/23883/3?u=duyluong):

1. Manually download chromedriver at https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=74.0.3729.6/ 83.
2. Extract and replace the current chromedriver in:

   - Windows 32bit: /configuration/resources/drivers/chromedriver_win32
   - Windows 64bit: /configuration/resources/drivers/chromedriver_win64
   - macOS: /Applications/Katalon Studio.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/resources/drivers/chromedriver_mac
   - Linux: /configuration/resources/drivers/chromedriver_linux64
3. For macOS and Linux machine: Set chromedriver to executable: chmod +x chromedriver and open Katalon Studio again.

Comment: In katalon studio not able to select the workflow. when i giving xpath and highlight means its running first time only. next time it displaying error

Comment: That sounds like a completely different issue. Is the problem with the Chrome version solved?